# leptonica/allheaders.h is missing for tesseocr installation on M1 macs with homebrew

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pip, python-tesseract, leptonica

i was trying to install normcap for OCR reading of images but i got into an error and don't understand how to solve it.

PC - Macbook M1 chipset
homebrew 3.1.7 installed and working fine.
CommandLinetools 12.5 have been installed(Apple).
Leptonica 1.80.0 is installed.
Tesseract 4.1.1 installed

```
asura@Asuras-MBP ~ % pip3 install tesserocr
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting tesserocr
  Using cached tesserocr-2.5.1.tar.gz (54 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: tesserocr
  Building wheel for tesserocr (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/w4/n1pwmphn6j13trrwzlzjbpzh0000gn/T/pip-install-44_kap26/tesserocr_10c3c6f9825d4363b69446dbd439cf21/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/w4/n1pwmphn6j13trrwzlzjbpzh0000gn/T/pip-install-44_kap26/tesserocr_10c3c6f9825d4363b69446dbd439cf21/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/w4/n1pwmphn6j13trrwzlzjbpzh0000gn/T/pip-wheel-vmhekyq6
       cwd: /private/var/folders/w4/n1pwmphn6j13trrwzlzjbpzh0000gn/T/pip-install-44_kap26/tesserocr_10c3c6f9825d4363b69446dbd439cf21/
  Complete output (16 lines):
  /private/var/folders/w4/n1pwmphn6j13trrwzlzjbpzh0000gn/T/pip-install-44_kap26/tesserocr_10c3c6f9825d4363b69446dbd439cf21/setup.py:72: SyntaxWarning: "is not" with a literal. Did you mean "!="?
    if subversion is not None and subversion is not "":
  Supporting tesseract v4.1.1
  Building with configs: {'libraries': ['tesseract', 'lept'], 'cython_compile_time_env': {'TESSERACT_VERSION': 67174656}}
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'tesserocr' extension
  creating build
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c tesserocr.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/tesserocr.o -std=c++11 -DUSE_STD_NAMESPACE
  tesserocr.cpp:663:10: fatal error: 'leptonica/allheaders.h' file not found
  #include "leptonica/allheaders.h"
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  1 error generated.
  error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for tesserocr
  Running setup.py clean for tesserocr
Failed to build tesserocr
Installing collected packages: tesserocr
    Running setup.py install for tesserocr ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/w4/n1pwmphn6j13trrwzlzjbpzh0000gn/T/pip-install-44_kap26/tesserocr_10c3c6f9825d4363b69446dbd439cf21/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/w4/n1pwmphn6j13trrwzlzjbpzh0000gn/T/pip-install-44_kap26/tesserocr_10c3c6f9825d4363b69446dbd439cf21/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/w4/n1pwmphn6j13trrwzlzjbpzh0000gn/T/pip-record-qagqxk6s/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /Users/asura/Library/Python/3.8/include/python3.8/tesserocr
         cwd: /private/var/folders/w4/n1pwmphn6j13trrwzlzjbpzh0000gn/T/pip-install-44_kap26/tesserocr_10c3c6f9825d4363b69446dbd439cf21/
    Complete output (16 lines):
    /private/var/folders/w4/n1pwmphn6j13trrwzlzjbpzh0000gn/T/pip-install-44_kap26/tesserocr_10c3c6f9825d4363b69446dbd439cf21/setup.py:72: SyntaxWarning: "is not" with a literal. Did you mean "!="?
      if subversion is not None and subversion is not "":
    Supporting tesseract v4.1.1
    Building with configs: {'libraries': ['tesseract', 'lept'], 'cython_compile_time_env': {'TESSERACT_VERSION': 67174656}}
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'tesserocr' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8
    clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c tesserocr.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/tesserocr.o -std=c++11 -DUSE_STD_NAMESPACE
    tesserocr.cpp:663:10: fatal error: 'leptonica/allheaders.h' file not found
    #include "leptonica/allheaders.h"
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/w4/n1pwmphn6j13trrwzlzjbpzh0000gn/T/pip-install-44_kap26/tesserocr_10c3c6f9825d4363b69446dbd439cf21/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/w4/n1pwmphn6j13trrwzlzjbpzh0000gn/T/pip-install-44_kap26/tesserocr_10c3c6f9825d4363b69446dbd439cf21/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/w4/n1pwmphn6j13trrwzlzjbpzh0000gn/T/pip-record-qagqxk6s/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /Users/asura/Library/Python/3.8/include/python3.8/tesserocr Check the logs for full command output.
```

As per my knowledge i provided all the information needed if something is missing please let me know.
i'm new to homebrew but used linux OS's for sometime

and also is there a way i can install from Github or any repository directly on homebrew, like if some changes are made in git repository files i want to install them directly otherwise need to wait for realese of tar.gz or .dmg files

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to install tesserocr from pip. Indeed the build status is noted as **failing** as you can see on the PyPI link [here](https://pypi.org/project/tesserocr/).

So to install it, you need to conda install it with the following line :

```
conda install -c conda-forge tesserocr
```

Moreover you need to install tesseract with Homebrew as following :

```
brew install tesseract
```

Now if you try to run your script maybe you will have new error(s) indicating that some **dylib** are not found.

In order to solve this new problem(s) you need to create symbolic links (i.e. symlinks). In my case I needed to create those ones :

**N.B: Before doing the following lines, check if you have a folder named lib in /usr/local, if no then create it**

```
ln -s /opt/homebrew/Cellar/libarchive/3.6.2_1/lib/libarchive.13.dylib /usr/local/lib/libarchive.19.dylib
ln -s /opt/homebrew/Cellar/leptonica/1.82.0_1/lib/liblept.5.dylib /usr/local/lib
ln -s /opt/homebrew/Cellar/tesseract/5.3.0_1/lib/libtesseract.5.dylib /usr/local/lib
ln -s /opt/homebrew/Cellar/libtiff/4.4.0_1/lib/libtiff.5.dylib /usr/local/lib
```

Normally now you could be able to run your script.

Answer (score 1):

Include address should be: `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/leptonica/1.82.0/include` instead of `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/leptonica/1.82.0/include/leptonica`. If you can add the first path to your PATH variable it might work.

I had the same issue when I was running C++ code, I included the right path and the program found `leptonics/allheader.h` file.

Comment: that didn't help for me. Currently using an m2 mac

Answer (score 0):

First `brew install tesseract`.  Then `pip install tesserocr`.  Apparently the pip install depends on things from the brew install.

On pip 23.1.1, Python 3.10.11.  Also I'm on an older MacBook, not an M1, but I got the same error as the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix here, its for golang but might work for python too.
https://github.com/otiai10/gosseract/issues/234

Install with `brew install tesseract`

```
export LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/homebrew/lib"

export CPATH="/opt/homebrew/include"
```